# Azure API Management "rewrite url" - how to remove the URL prefix

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-api-management

I have a large number of public URLs starting with `/abc/*`, for example:

`/abc/user`

`/abc/login`

`/abc/group/admin`

How can I rewrite the URL rule to get rid of `/abc/*` like this:

`/user`

`/login`

`/group/admin`

I tried to set the URL template to `/abc/*`, and rewrite template is `/`. It seems the url template can get to know the above urls, but the rewrite template cannot write the result I want.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tested with your scenario - this gives you `/xxxx` as forwarding path for `/abc/xxxx`:

```
<rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(context.Api.Path+"/abc",""))" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
```

or to do it more generic:

```
<rewrite-uri template="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Replace(context.Api.Path+context.Operation.UrlTemplate.Replace("/*",""),""))" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
```